# SQL query to check for inclusion of any element from an array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a database column containing a string that might look something like this `u/1u/3u/19/g1/g4` for a particular row.

Is there a performant way to get all rows that have at least one of the following elements `['u/3', 'g4']` in that column?

I know I can use `AND` clauses, but the number of elements to verify against varies and could become large..

I am using RoR/ActiveRecord in my project.

Comment: I don't think that there is a dbms that wouldn't need a full table scan to produce results for that where clause. Can't you normalize that column to two tables with fk so inner joins can be used?

Comment: how would you construct the where clause (with a full table scan) if the array to check against varies in size though?

Comment: As I know there is no such method. Suggest to refactor db as @rene mentioned.

Comment: Is the string always sorted? Or is the order of the parts random? Which database are you using? Do you have control over the schema (e.g. can you change it?).

Comment: I control the sorting of the string, so could be sorted any way that would help..

Answer (score 0):

in sql server, you can use XML to convert your list of search params into a record set, then cross join that with the base table, and do charIndex() to see if the column contains the substring.

Since i don't know your table or column names, i used a table (persons) that i already had data in, which has a column 'phone_home'.  To search for any phone number that contains '202' or '785' i would use this query:

```
select  person_id,phone_home,Split.data.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)')
from    (select *, cast('<n>202</n><n>785</n>' as XML) as myXML
        from persons) as data cross apply myXML.nodes('/n') as Split(data)
where charindex(Split.data.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)'),data.phone_Home) > 0
```

you will get duplicate records if it matches more than one value, so throw a distinct in there and remove the Split from the select statement if that is not desired.

Using xml in sql is voodoo magic to me...i got the idea from this post http://www.sqljason.com/2010/05/converting-single-comma-separated-row.html

no idea what performance is like...but at least there aren't any cursors or dynamic sql.

EDIT: Casting the XML is pretty slow, so i made it a variable so it only gets cast once.

```
declare @xml XML
set @xml = cast('<n>202</n><n>785</n>' as XML)

select  person_id,phone_home,Split.persons.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)')
from    persons cross apply @xml.nodes('/n') as Split(persons)
where charindex(Split.persons.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)'),phone_Home) > 0
```